# Why are there multiple copies of figures in Gaming Night Kits

Tags: zombicide

I'm curious as to why there are 6 copies of the same miniature an corresponding ID cards in the Gaming Night Kits. I understand the different languages ID cards copies of the same miniature? I would of expected 1 miniature and three ID cards (one for each language) however i get 6 miniatures and 18 cards (6 for each language).

Does this mean that I can play with the same character in the same game and there are no restrictions for the same survivor? So if I owned multiple copies of the game I could technically have a team of all the same survivor?
Does anyone know if there is a rule that stops this from happening or why the gaming night kits bring 6 miniatures?

Comment: The product is intended to be used to run a game-day in a store or club where the miniatures are prizes for the participants.  This is why it comes with multiples.

Comment: @Affe That sounds like an answer; mind posting it as one?

Comment: @Affe do you know if there is any rule that prevents from using the same survivor?

Answer (score 1):

Most gaming kits come with supplies to provide prize support for multiple people (whether it be players, people who help moderate the events, or other qualifications).

Regarding playing the same character, there's nothing that prevents you from doing this, although typically you'd want to have more diversity of roles (and some characters could make the game much easier with multiple copies.)  The other issue is that without painting your minis or otherwise making them distinct, it could be hard to determine which of the 4 identical minis represent you!